# Organizing CUDA kernels

Tags: gpu, cuda

I am writing a very very long CUDA kernel, and it is pretty awful for human readability. Is there any way to organize CUDA kernels with functions for example outside of the kernel?
Example:

```
__global__ void CUDA_Kernel(int* a, int* b){
     //calling function 1
     //calling function 2
     //calculation function
         .......
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function can be called from inside a kernel if it is defined using the __device__  keyword.

For example:

```
__device__ int test_fun(int val)
{
   return 2*val + 3;
}


__global__ void kern_test( int * data) 
{
   int aOffset = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   data[offset] = test_fun(data[offset]);
}
```

Comment: and can a __device__ call another __device__ ??

Comment: A \_\_device__ function should have no problem calling another \_\_device__ function. Note that these are generally inlined and if a \_\_device__ function calls __itself__ then this is a recursive call and only supported in cards with compute capability 2.x or higher (see [this table](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)).

Answer (score 4):

Yep.  Define and call device functions:

```
__device__ float foo(float x, float y) {
 return x+y*x;
}
```